# JMeter TearDown Issue

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, jmeter

Hi everyone in my Test i have this lineup:

[jmeter set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQGNY.png)

In the thread group the duration is set to 300 sec.
My goal is to make the first 3 requests in a time X sec (**about 10**), make those in the loop count for Y sec (**180 sec, with loop count equal to 1000**) and the last two for Z sec (**about 10**). 
another question is: if the lifetime thread ends before the whole loop controller is executed, I want the last two requests to act as teardowns. How can I set them?
Can anyone give me some advice on how to act?

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to make the first 3 requests in a time X sec (about 10)

and

> last two for Z sec (about 10).

this is achievable by [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler

> make those in the loop count for Y sec (180 sec, with loop count equal to 1000)

Put "those" under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), mention the start time via [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and put an [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) somewhere inside the Loop Controller to compare current time with the start time, if it exceeds 180 seconds - use the aforementioned Flow Control Action sampler to exit the loop

---

With regards to your "another question" I think you should rather start a new thread, it's quite hard to answer several "another" questions and it makes the process of searching for the answer for other people harder.

Whatever.

Currently I would recommend to use:

- [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) for preparing the test data or the system for the load test
- [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) for cleaning up
- eventually you can use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and [__P() functions combination](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) to pass the data between thread groups

If you need to implement the tearDown within the bounds of a single Thread Group - either go for the above approach with Loop Controller + If Controller + __time() function or go for [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)